# Why is xgboost not plotting my trees?

Tags: r, plot, xgboost

I am running xgboost model as follows:

```
bst <- xgb.train(data=dtrain, booster="gbtree", objective="reg:linear",
    max.depth=5, nround=20, watchlist=watchlist,min_child_weight=10)
importance_matrix <- xgb.importance(names, model = bst)
xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix[1:10,])
```

Variable-importance matrix is plotted nicely but when I do following

```
xgb.plot.tree(feature_names = names, model = bst, n_first_tree = 2)
```

RStudio opens a new browser window and shows lots of HTML, but no image. The HTML has all the details like the scripts needed to create graphs etc. but I dont have these java scripts and I was thinking it should just work like plotting the importance-matrix.

What am I missing?

Comment: Same issue for me.

Comment: I had to fix up your formatting and typos. Please use Code-formatting, not Blockquoting, on code. Also, this is not an RStudio issue, you could have tested that by rerunning just in R.

Comment: Also it helps if you tell us what versions of R and xgboost: 4.4 had some known issues.

Answer (score 0):

If a tree has only one node then it will not be plotted, and that's the case for your first two trees. You can dump your tree first via `xgb.dump`and see which trees have more than one node, and increase the `n_first_tree` value accordingly.