# Function xgb.plot.tree() doesn't work

Tags: r, plot, xgboost

I am trying to estimate an extreme gradiant boosting model using `(xgboost)` package.
Before writing this question, I looked for infos both on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but the informations that I found did not solve my problem.
Those are the posts that are similar to this that I found, but they have not been solved in a clear way:

[human readable rules from xgboost in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698231/human-readable-rules-from-xgboost-in-r)

[xbg.plot.tree() crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401755/xbg-plot-tree-crashes)

[Why is xgboost not plotting my trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960539/why-is-xgboost-not-plotting-my-trees)

My problem is with the function `xgb.plot.tree`, I built my extreme gradiant boosting model with `xgboost()` function, I created matrix that shows importance of features in a model with `xgb.importance()`, but when I try to plot a boosted tree model, the function crashes.

Below my R-code:

```
model_xgb <- xgboost(data=dtrain$data, 
             label=dtrain$label,
             booster="gbtree",
             max_depth=6, 
             eta=0.3, 
             nthread=2, 
             nrounds = 150, 
             verbose=0,
             eval_metrics=list("error"),
             objective="binary:logistic")

# Calculate feature importance

imp <- xgb.importance(feature_names=dtrain$data@Dimnames[[2]], 
                      model=model_xgb)

print(imp)

# Display tree number 1
xgb.plot.tree(feature_names=dtrain$data@Dimnames[[2]],
              model=model_xgb,
              n_first_tree=1)
```

According with the answer of @ArriveW I added the function `xgb.dump()` and I modified my code as below:

```
dump_xgb <- xgb.dump(model = model_xgb)

xgb.plot.tree(feature_names=dtrain$data@Dimnames[[2]],
              model=model_xgb,
              n_first_tree=5)
```

But despite this, I do not get a chart and this is the result

[image]

On github you can find the reproducible example:

[CreditRiskPrediction](https://github.com/Microsoft/acceleratoRs/blob/master/CreditRiskPrediction/Code/CreditRiskPrediction.Rmd)

Any suggestion please?